# Redirecting with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect with `react-router-dom`. This is what I was doing so far:

```
export function login() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
                document.getElementById('close').click();
                document.getElementById('questions').click();
            }
        ).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

So I was simply clicking the link to redirect the user where I need them to go. But the code changed, and this won't work anymore. So far I worked with `Express` for node, and redirection was done by a simple `res.redirect('path');`.

I did some research, but cannot see any ***current*** answer to my question. How is it supposed to be done now? I tried using history, but that's deprecated. I saw something like `withRouter`, the last line always threw me off:

```
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Example from [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Also I do not have a class in my case. It's just an exported method, so there is no constructor, or `render()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React router has a [redirect element](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) which you can conditionally render once your login is done.

This will require a render, which you said you do not have, what you can do is create a login component:

```
class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    yourLoginFunction().then(() => this.setState({loggedIn: true});
  }

  render() {
    const {loggedIn} = this.state;
    if(loggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to="/post/login/path" />
    } else {
      return <div>login in progress...</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So there is no simple "Just add this to the url and press enter" way of doing it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you draft what you had in mind?

Comment: In `Express.js` all I had to do was `res.redirect('/new/path');`. I'm guessing something as simple as this is impossible in React?

Comment: You have the alternative of getting a hold of the router and use its navigation methods, but getting it might be a bit of work

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my React Project:

At the top:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

In the class:

```
  static propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

For the redirect:

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

At the bottom of the file:

```
export default withRouter(CourseDetail);
```

Comment: So how are you supposed to import it in the other file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react router if you have a class based component or something like that. If you have a function like your login example i think you should use something like `window.location = my_new_path`

Comment: I knew there is an easier way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Easier, but not the correct one. You're using `react-router-dom`, therefore the right way is using its API, and not relying to the window object.

Comment: And if you're using the router, this type of redirect might bypass it and loose current state